# Cannot convert datetime to string SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to convert date time to string. In my SQL query, I have a date "2016/06/15". With this date, I am subtracting it one month "2016/05/15".
I got this part working. However, when I am trying to convert it to a string (varchar or nvarchar), I encounter the following exception. **Conversion failed when converting date time from character string.** I am not sure how to fix this, help will be appreciated.

Here is my query

```
Declare @date as datetime
Set @date = GetDate()
print @date
Declare @dateMinusOneMonth as datetime
Set @dateMinusOneMonth = GetDate() 
Set @dateMinusOneMonth = Convert(nvarchar, Convert(nvarchar(3), DateAdd(month, -1, @date)), 101)
print @dateMinusOneMonth
```

Comment: I think converting isn't `Sql Server` task. Convert values in your `C#` code

Comment: Shows how much Fabio knows. CONVERT( {Interval}, {expression}, {style} ) is a function in SQL SERVER.[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring `@dateMinusOneMonth` as `datetime`. Do it like this:

```
Declare @dateMinusOneMonth as nvarchar(20)
Set @dateMinusOneMonth = Convert(nvarchar, Convert(nvarchar(3), DateAdd(month, -1, @date)), 101)
```

Comment: Yeah, @DragonBorn, hopefully you noted the length of the string (20). That can mess up your code if you do not take care.

Answer (score 2):

`@dateMinusOneMonth` is of type `datetime` and you are trying to assign it `varchar` value which is not valid.

You can convert it in `print` like below

```
Set @dateMinusOneMonth = DateAdd(month, -1, @date)    
print Convert(nvarchar, Convert(nvarchar(3), DateAdd(month, -1, @dateMinusOneMonth)), 101)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets first focus on transforming it to VARCHAR/NVARCHAR. Just pass the variable like this:

```
DECLARE @Time DATE
SET @Time = CAST(DATEADD(MM, -1, GETDATE() ) AS DATE ) 
SELECT CAST(@TIME AS VARCHAR(10) )
```

See how easy that was?

Result: `2016-05-14`

Please note that your DB may be set up differently, and you should test or format the dates correctly.
Lastly, if you use TRY_CONVERT(), the answer will return a NULL instead of failing the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in one line easily.  also I don't like having to look up 101, 102,113, etc for date string formats with convert.  seeing you mention c# if you are on SQL 2012 or newer just use FORMAT like you would in c#.

```
PRINT FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()), 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```